# FlexLayout isn't displaying the bindable data in .NET Maui?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am working on a .NET MAUI app where it displays a list of available genres above and a collection of movies bellow. I was attempting to use FlexLayout but I can't seem to get it to work. Whenever I run the app the data (Genres, Movies) are blank. I have tried this with collection view and it works no problem so I figured I am doing something wrong with the FlexLayout. There has to be something I'm doing wrong with the code bellow. But what is it? Thanks for the help!

```
<VerticalStackLayout Spacing="10"
                     Padding="30">

    <Border Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5">
        
        <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="20">
           
            <Label Text="Genres:"/>
            
            <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Genres}"
                        JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Stroke="CadetBlue"
                                StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15">
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   Padding="10"
                                   BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </FlexLayout>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Border>

    <ScrollView>
        <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}"
                    JustifyContent="SpaceBetween"
                    Wrap="Wrap">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="100"
                                         Margin="30"
                                         Spacing="10">

                        <Image Source="{Binding poster_path}"
                               Aspect="AspectFit">
                            <Image.Shadow>
                                <Shadow Brush="Black"
                                        Opacity="0.6"
                                        Offset="5,5"
                                        Radius="20"/>
                            </Image.Shadow>
                        </Image>
                        
                        <HorizontalStackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding title}"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   WidthRequest="150"
                                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                            
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                   WidthRequest="50"
                                   Text="{Binding vote_average, StringFormat='{0} ⭐'}"/>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </FlexLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Same code works on my end.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem in FlexLayout. It has nothing to do with bindable data. I wrote a simple demo based on your code. I didn’t use bindable in it, and it still shows blank in the simulator. You can use `StackLayout` and `Grid` to replace FlexLayout Solve the problem.

There are some mentioned issues on GitHub, you can follow up:

[Layout Cycle Detected when a Flexlayout is inside a StackLayout on Windows #11909](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11909)

[FlexLayout trigger Cycle GUI exception #9075](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9075)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I will look into this! It's weird because I was able to get FlexLayout to work on a separate app where I was just displaying text a certain way. I wonder what's the hold up?

Comment: Yes, it can be displayed normally alone, but there will be problems when nested in StackLayout. You can use other layouts temporarily, which is closer to the issue in GitHub.